# Java regex matcher doesn't group as expected

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex

```
.*?(\\d+.*?\\d*).*?-.*?(\\d+.*?\\d*).*?
```

I want to match any string that contains a numerical value followed by "-" and another number. Any string can be in between.

Also, I want to be able to extract the numbers using group function of Java Matcher class.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+.*?\\d*).*?-.*?(\\d+.*?\\d*).*?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("13.9 mp - 14.9 mp");
matcher.matches();
```

I expect this result:

```
matcher.group(1) // this should be 13.9 but it is 13 instead
matcher.group(2) // this should be 14.9 but it is 14 instead
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Escape the dots in `\d+.*\d*` or better, use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current pattern has several problems.  As others have pointed out, your dots should be escaped with two backslashes if you intend for them to be literal dots.  I think the pattern you want to use to match a number which may or may not have a decimal component is this:

```
(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)
```

This matches the following:

```
\\d+          one or more numbers
(?:\\.\\d+)?  followed by a decimal point and one or more numbers
              this entire quantity being optional
```

Full code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*?-.*?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("13.9 mp - 14.9 mp");
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
13.9
14.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.*?(\d+\.*\d*).*?-.*?(\d+\.*\d*).*?
```

. between '\d+' and '*\d*' in your regex should be changed to \.

Comment: This would match a sentence ending in a number.  Have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/9PHnDn/1).

Comment: the regex is Jones's ,I just modify it to matche value he want .Maybe that is he want.